# Else if statements with toUpperCase(), toLowerCase() and Number.isInteger()

Tags: javascript, if-statement, statements

Hoping you can help me again with a query I have.
I'm trying to create a script which asks the user to either input a lowercase letter, a uppercase letter or a number, then depending on what they enter they will get back a response such as the following as an example “g is a lowercase letter.”

I have just started learning about else if statements so would appreciate some help with this one as the toUpperCase(), toLowerCase() and Number.isInteger() has thrown me off abit.

Thanks for any help you can give :)

Comment: It would help if you post what you have so far so people can suggest improvements or guide you in the next step :)

Comment: What are your input parameter? Only letters and digits?

Comment: Yes only letters and digits :)